# BeautifulSoup returns empty span elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull prices from Binance's home page and BeautifulSoup returns empty elements for me. Binance's home page is at https://www.binance.com/en/, and the interesting block I'm trying to get text from is:

```
<div class="sc-62mpio-0-sc-iAyFgw iQwJlO" color="#999"><span>"/" "$" "35.49"</span></div>
```

On Binance's home page is a table and one of the columns is titled "Last Price". Next to the last price is the last USD price in a faded gray color and I'm trying to pull every one of those. Here's my code so far.

```
def grabPrices():
    page = requests.get("https://www.binance.com/en")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

    prices = soup.find_all("span", {"class": None})
    print(prices)
```

But the output is just a large array of "–" tags.

Comment: The web site uses AJAX to replace all the dashes with the current values. BS doesn't run JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium should be one way of scraping the table content you want from this biniance page. And google Selenium about its set up (pretty much by download a driver and place it in your local disk, if you are a chrome user, see this download link [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/)). Here is my code to access the content you are interested:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(3) # Allow time to launch the controlled web
driver.get('https://www.binance.com/en/')
time.sleep(3) # Allow time to load the page
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
Table = sel.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div')
Table.extract() # This basically gives you all the content of the table, see follow screen shot (screen shot is truncated for display purpose)
```

[image]

Then if you further process the entire table content with something like:

```
tb_rows = Table.xpath('.//div/a//div//div//span/text()').extract()
tb_rows # Then you will get follow screen shot
```

[image]

At this point, the result is narrowed down to pretty much what you are interested, but notice that the lastprice's two components (number/dollar price) are stored in two  tag in source page, so we can do following to combine them together and reach to the destination:

```
for n in range(0,len(tb_rows),2):
    LastPrice = tb_rows[n] + tb_rows[n+1]
    print(LastPrice) # For sure, other than print, you could store each element in a list
driver.quit() # don't forget to quit driver by the end
```

The final output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used selenium with BeautifulSoup because I couldn't get the Selector class to be defined, but it worked!

Comment: Glad it works. I've just updated my answer to complete this method though, feel free to adopt anything helpful. One possible reason why your selector can not be defined may be because if you ran my previous code in one shot (other than do it step by step such as in jupyter notebook), the code is processed faster than the web is loaded, so that selector can not find the page source content. The solution is to add time.sleep() within the code to allow time to let page be loaded before processing  (I've updated that part as well).